# Nano V3 values "overwritten" randomly

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano

When I assign a global var to a certain value inside an if-block it has been changed to another value in the next statement. Somehow the address of the var is overwritten by some other process. It also does not stop at 1 value, this happens to the next vars that are assigned another value too. The vars are not defined in a row but should be close.
I already installed a newer version of Arduino IDE, no change.
Example:

```
menuActive=1;
Serial.print(menuActive);
```

gives results in the range 40 to 57 as far as I have seen till now. Further actions assign always the SAME value to next vars I assign after this.
Anyone some idea what could cause this? Am I low on memory for local vars?
This is compile message:

```
Sketch uses 21790 bytes (70%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.
Global variables use 1454 bytes (70%) of dynamic memory, leaving 594 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
```

edit:

As I already said, it is 21k of code. But I show you the part of the code that mishaves:

```
while ((digitalRead(rotSwPin) == 0) && lpress <= 200) {
    delay(10);
    lpress++;
    if (lpress > 200) {
        menuActive++;
        menuLvl=0;
        menuPos=0;
        subPos=0;
    }
}
```

Normally I use menuActive=1. Within the braces, it is still 1, out of that it changes. Maybe change from byte to bool.

Comment: Sounds like a buffer overflow to me.

Comment: Agreed! But where can I find the memory assignment in a file/list to grab an idea which variable does the overwriting?

Comment: You can't unless you generate a "map" file, for which you need to modify the compiler options in the IDE configuration files.  Examine your code for any arrays that you use and make sure you don't try and use more than you should. One common misuse is to declare `int foo[10]` and then try and use `foo[10]` as a slice.

Comment: Given the range of numbers it gives you, chances are it's a char array into which you are printing numbers, maybe with punctuation like brackets.

Comment: or show your code and someone spots the problem

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I checked those things already carefully. I think of stepping to Eclipse for this Arduino project and find out more by debugging?

Comment: As I already said, it is 21k of code. But I show you the part of the code that mishaves: 
<code>
while ((digitalRead(rotSwPin) == 0) && lpress <= 200) { delay(10);lpress++; if (lpress > 200) {menuActive++;menuLvl=0;menuPos=0;subPos=0;} } 
</code>
Normally I use menuActive=1. 
Within the braces, it is still 1, out of that it changes. Maybe change from byte to bool.

Comment: If your program corrupts memory (which seems to be the case here), the part of the code that misbehaves can be quite far from the part that does the memory corruption. There is nothing wrong with the code you are showing here. Your problem lies in some part of the code you are not showing. Nobody will be able to help you without seeing the bug.

Comment: I found the problem.
I could see that the false value is the character code of the minute I am displaying. I display hours and minutes and there was a declaration that was 3 characters short for the string I got as a result for hours added to minutes. Yes it was memory corruption. 
So be careful to dimension enough places for your strings including 1 extra for 0.

Comment: @hoekbrwr You might want to post that as an answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: Comments are not recommended for any of the following: [Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment);. Feel free to post an answer instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I could see that the false value is the character code of the minute I am displaying. I display hours and minutes and there was a declaration that was 3 characters short for the string I got as a result for hours added to minutes. Yes, it was memory corruption. So be very careful to dimension enough places for your C-strings including 1 extra for 0. If you are not so short on RAM then a few more characters will do no harm, the end of the string will be the character before the 0 in memory.
When strange things happen start looking at this matter!